# HTML5 video not playing on iPad - black screen

Tags: ipad, html, ios-simulator, html5-video

I've seen various posts related to my issue, but none have helped me solve my problem. I have an HTML5 webapp for iPad that I want some video displayed in. I use the video tag with controls and just see a black screen where the video is supposed to go. I have the video properly encoded for iPad and it plays fine in Safari, but when I try to use the iPad simulator I just see the black area. I tried making a barebones web page with only the video on it and still nothing works. What could be the problem?

Comment: I am not sure whether MPEG4 playback was enabled on the  emulator. Have you tried on actual device?

Comment: I did try on the actual device and it was the same problem. Since I posted, I tried Video.js and got the video to finally play in my barebones page as a stand alone video. My webapp needs dynamically changing videos, so I need to figure that out now.

Comment: iOS does not dynamic video and automatic start. All playback must be touch-to-play.

Comment: Right, I have a rotating ad system that includes some picture ads and some video ads, so I need to change the source every once in a while.

Comment: I suggest you test it out before you hit the limitations the all-loved Apple has set for you :)